# How do I autofill a formula referring to a column into a row on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I made a Spreadsheet to link with a form, but the form responses are added automatically with a horizontal header on the top. I want a vertical header on the left, so I created another sheet and used the formula `='Form Responses 1'!##` to copy data from the form responses sheet to the new sheet. But when I try to autofill each row, it doesn't follow the order I want. I need it to fill like this:

```
='Form Responses 1'!A2 | ='Form Responses 1'!A3 | ='Form Responses 1'!A4
```

But it fills like this instead:

```
='Form Responses 1'!A2 | ='Form Responses 1'!B2 | ='Form Responses 1'!C2
```

What can I do to autofill my formula correctly across 30+ columns on each of my 7 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to transpose columns into rows. This is what the [`transpose`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) formula is for. In cell A1 of the second sheet, enter

```
=transpose('Form Responses 1'!A:Z)
```